# Creating dictionary from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I want to create a dictionary out of my data frame. Data frame look like this:

```
Vehical | Brand  | Model Name
car     | Suzuki | abc 
car     | Honda  | def
bike    | Suzuki | xyz
bike    | Honda  | asd
```

I want my dictionary like:

```
{car : {Suzuki : abc, Honda : def}, bike : {Suzuki : xyz, Honda : asd}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [29]: df.pivot(index='Vehical', columns='Brand', values='Model Name').to_dict('i')
Out[29]:
{'bike': {'Honda': 'asd', 'Suzuki': 'xyz'},
 'car': {'Honda': 'def', 'Suzuki': 'abc'}}
```

result of pivoting:

```
In [28]: df.pivot(index='Vehical', columns='Brand', values='Model Name')
Out[28]:
Brand   Honda Suzuki
Vehical
bike      asd    xyz
car       def    abc
```